# How to combine different sets of word embeddings?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, word-embedding

I am building a semantic relations classifier.

Example of "cause-effect" relation: "**Zinc** is essential for **growth** and cell division."

For this I am using pretrained word embeddings from Spacy as I don´t have anough data to train my own. I took two approaches:

1. took the two words that are related (or not) and calculated their cosine similarity using their word embeddings and used that as feature vector for a MLP classifier.
2. took the mean vector of the entire sentence and used it as feature vector for the MLP classifier.
   But the results on test data are not very good (aprox 50% precision and recall). I think the results could improve by combinig both approaches, but I don´t really know how to do that.

I am using a multilayer perceptron with one hidden layer of 150 nodes.

Here is the code of the first approach:

```
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_md') #these are the embeddings

entities_vec=np.zeros((len(entity1), 300))
for i in range(len(entity1)):
    doc1=nlp(entity1[i])
    doc2=nlp(entity2[i])
    entities_vec[i,:]=(sum(doc1.vector, doc2.vector))*0.5
```

Here´s the code of the second approach:

```
sentences_vec=np.zeros((len(sentences), 300))
for i in range(len(sentences)):
    doc=nlp(sentences[i])
    sentences_vec[i,:]=doc.vector
```

I tried adding sentences_vec and entities_vec but that threw even worse results on test data. What would be a way to improve the model?

Comment: How about your methods work on train data? Whether or not they are overfitting? What is the size of your train samples?

Comment: Both models perform very good In train data , I increased the alpha to see if the problem was overfitting and it improved a little, but not much. I have 140 sentences for each relation ( I check the performance on 40 and train on 100 to check for overfitting)

Comment: So, has Overfiting happened?  How many relation do you have? If the size of your train data is larger than 10000,  did you have try deeper and wider network?
Did you try `dropout`, `L2` or `L1` ?

Comment: There are 7 different relations but I am building binary classifiers for each of them. There are only 140 training examples for each relation. I think there’s overfitting, to solve that I increased the alpha of the MLP as much as I could without making the results worse. I also used deeper and wider networks but I think that made the overfitting worse.

Comment: For fewer samples and more features,  `SVM` and `KNN` maybe more better.

Comment: whether or not it's work?